# Secure Boot makes newly installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS crash

Tags: boot, nvidia, uefi

Dear ubuntu community,

I am a beginner in the Linux world. I have some problems while trying to install ubuntu on my laptop. It has following specs:

Dell XPS 15 9560,
Intel Core i7-7700HQ,
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050, 
512 GB PCIe SSD, 
16 GB DDR4 RAM.

Curruently i'm running Windows 10 Home N and want to switch to ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. I created a bootable USB flash drive using rufus. I try to boot from the USB drive in UEFI boot mode with secure boot mode ON. I also checked the integrity of the installation files - no error was reported.

Whenever i try to boot form the USB drive in this settings, ubuntu is starting and runnig for about 3 minutes. Then it crashes and the lines in the attached picture are shown.[UbuntuCrash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR59X.jpg)

As far as I understand it, there is a hard drive failure. Does anyone have an idea why the error occurs and how I can fix it?

I hope I have given enough information about my system. If you need more information please let me know.

I would really like to try ubuntu and I am not ready to give up yet ;). Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I don't see any attached picture, but if you are seeing IO errors it's likely your install media. Did you verify the downloaded ISO was perfect (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and I think more importantly the write to your install media was flawless? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck where CD is whatever media was used, cd/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/etc)

Comment: Disable Secure Boot, boot with `nomodeset`, then install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much!!